# How to access object using index notation

Tags: javascript, json, jsonlite

I am trying to make an object using table data

```
 var cond = [
        { 
    "locality": "Dwarka",
    "Created ->OFP": "4.73",
    "OFP -> Picked": "2.16",
    "Picked - > Delivery": "14.91",
    "Over_All_TAT": "22.65",
    "Total_Order": "159" 
  },
  {
    "locality": "IIT & AIIMS",
    "Created ->OFP": "2.56",
    "OFP -> Picked": "9.74",
    "Picked - > Delivery": "19.41",
    "Over_All_TAT": "32.61",
    "Total_Order": "54"
  },
  {
    "locality": "Gk1 & Nehru Place",
    "Created ->OFP": "2.39",
    "OFP -> Picked": "6.87",
    "Picked - > Delivery": "14.06",
    "Over_All_TAT": "24.13",
    "Total_Order": "31"
  },
  {
    "locality": "Mayur Vihar",
    "Created ->OFP": "3.52",
    "OFP -> Picked": "1.24",
    "Picked - > Delivery": "15.3",
    "Over_All_TAT": "21.03",
    "Total_Order": "33"
  },
  {
    "locality": "Snapdeal_Mundhka",
    "Created ->OFP": "17.32",
    "OFP -> Picked": "4.65",
    "Picked - > Delivery": "100.32",
    "Over_All_TAT": "123.16",
    "Total_Order": "31"
  }
  ]
```

I know the key names are not  according to the rules , but those are the column names. Can i access the 2nd column say Created -> OFP *using index* (e.g. `cond[0][1]`).

I am able to access only `cond[i]` How can i access the inner block elements.

As I am using R , The json object is created using jsonlite package, So, I have limitations.

Comment: Like that : `cond[i]['Created ->OFP']`

Comment: That isn't JSON its a plain JavaScript object. JSON is just a string format that represents an object. It would be parsed with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Kay and Craicerjack: It looks like a dupe, but I don't believe they are actually asking the same thing. The OP wants to access the nested object using numeric indexes rather than the property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access your element like this :

```
cond[i]["Created ->OFP"]; // "4.73"
```

---

if you want to use indexes like 1, 2, you have two choices:
using an array instead of objects, and it will look like this :

```
 var cond = [
        ["Dwarka", "4.73", "2.16", "14.91", "22.65", "159" ],
        [ ... ]
  }
```

or you can use the indexes 1, 2 ... on your object which will be like this:

```
var cond = [
        { 
    "0": "Dwarka",
    "1": "4.73",
    "2": "2.16",
    "3": "14.91",
    "4": "22.65",
    "5": "159" 
  },
  {...}
]
```

but you won't find the property `length` unless you add it as an element to your object.

---

I think the best solution for you, is to keep your object as it is, and use the loop `for(key in cond)`

```
for(var i=0; i<cond.length; i++) {
    for(var key in cond[i]) {
       console.log(cond[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @R3tep  I want to use column  number . like 2 , 3 and say on

Comment: @MukeshKumarSingh: You can't. The ordering of keys in a javascript object is not guaranteed. If you need to be able to access things by a numeric index, then you need an array.

Comment: @MukeshKumarSingh, check updates

Comment: @Khalid: The order that keys are iterated with `for...in` is not guaranteed. It will probably work most of the time, but it's very bad practice to rely on it. You are essentially tying yourself to a particular implementation of `for...in`.

Answer (score 2):

You can access on the inner block like this :

```
cond[i]['Created ->OFP']
```

Example with loop :

```js
var cond = [{
  "locality": "Dwarka",
  "Created ->OFP": "4.73",
  "OFP -> Picked": "2.16",
  "Picked - > Delivery": "14.91",
  "Over_All_TAT": "22.65",
  "Total_Order": "159"
}, {
  "locality": "IIT & AIIMS",
  "Created ->OFP": "2.56",
  "OFP -> Picked": "9.74",
  "Picked - > Delivery": "19.41",
  "Over_All_TAT": "32.61",
  "Total_Order": "54"
}, {
  "locality": "Gk1 & Nehru Place",
  "Created ->OFP": "2.39",
  "OFP -> Picked": "6.87",
  "Picked - > Delivery": "14.06",
  "Over_All_TAT": "24.13",
  "Total_Order": "31"
}, {
  "locality": "Mayur Vihar",
  "Created ->OFP": "3.52",
  "OFP -> Picked": "1.24",
  "Picked - > Delivery": "15.3",
  "Over_All_TAT": "21.03",
  "Total_Order": "33"
}, {
  "locality": "Snapdeal_Mundhka",
  "Created ->OFP": "17.32",
  "OFP -> Picked": "4.65",
  "Picked - > Delivery": "100.32",
  "Over_All_TAT": "123.16",
  "Total_Order": "31"
}]
var val;
cond.forEach(function(el) {
  val = el['Created ->OFP'];
  console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: For specific columns: `cond[0]['Created ->OFP']`, `cond[1]['Created ->OFP']`, etc etc

Comment: From the edits to the original question and the comments of the OP, I don't think this is actually what they were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, what you'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
cond[0][1];   // "4.73"
```

You can't do that because `cond[0]` is and object and the order of keys in an object isn't guaranteed. So just because `Created ->OFP` is your second key *as you entered it* doesn't mean it's actually the second key in the object. You could look at `Object.keys(cond[0])` and the keys will *probably* come back in the same order, but you *cannot rely on this*.

What it sounds like you need to do is transform the objects in your array (which isn't JSON as others have pointed out) into arrays themselves. So you end up with something like:

```
[
    [
        "Dwarka",
        "4.73",
        "2.16",
        "14.91",
        "22.65",
        "159"
    ],...
]
```

And then you could do:

```
cond[0][1];   //and get the first row and second column.
```

To transform your original into an array of arrays, you can do something like this:

```
// Note: this is the order **you** want the columns to be iterated in
var columns = ["locality",
    "Created ->OFP",
    "OFP -> Picked",
    "Picked - > Delivery",
    "Over_All_TAT",
    "Total_Order"];

var arrayOfArrays = cond.map(function (i) {
    return columns.map(function (prop) {
        return i[prop];
    });
});

console.log(arrayOfArrays[0][1]);   // logs 4.73
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1570cthr/)